# How can I retrieve the citations for a given book using the Amazon API?

Tags: api

I know of a website which, if given the ISBN, populates all the information like author, pages, and even images of a book, using Amazon. How is this done?

I am trying to compile a reading list. I have a seed reading list of books and I want to collect the bibliography of those books and then I want to find out which book is the most cited and then I would be able to find the most important books to read. But right now all I see is to parse their webpages which is not a very pleasant and elegant way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

If you read anything about AWS (like here: http://aws.amazon.com/what-is-aws/) you would see AWS has nothing to do with Amazon's store content.

Comment: Yeah I got it. But I know of a website which if given the ISBN it populates all the information like author, pages, and even images of the book. So I wonder how to make this possible. I need this badly because I am trying to compile a reading list. I have a seed reading list of books and I want to collect the bibliography of those books and then I want to find out which book is the most cited and then I would be able to find the most important books to read. But right now all I see is to parse their webpages which is not a very pleasant and elegant way of doing this.